# Swing - scroll JFrame content without using scrollbars

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jframe

I have following problem. Is there a way to scroll Jframe content without using scrollbars, just to do it programatically in code. I have Japplet inside and I can't find a way to scroll its content without showing scrolls. Whole scrolling action should be performed not on user action, but when my thread wants to do so. Waiting for help, thanks.

I can't find any way to do that. I was trying to add my component (Applet) to Jscrollpane and that to jframe, but it causes situation, when only white screen is displayed.

JFrame class:

```
public class SimulationFrame extends JFrame {

    private SimulationWindow simulationWindow;

    public SimulationFrame() throws HeadlessException {
        super(PropertiesHelper.getWindowTitle());

        simulationWindow = new SimulationWindow();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(simulationWindow);
        this.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

JComponent:

```
    public SimulationWindow() {

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    graph = GraphHelper.provideGraphInstance();

    Dimension layoutSize = new Dimension(PropertiesHelper.getGraphHolderWidth(),
                                         PropertiesHelper.getGraphHolderHeight());
    graphLayout = new StaticLayout<Checkpoint, Route>(graph, new CheckpointPositionTransformer());
    graphLayout.setSize(layoutSize);

    visualizationViewer = new VisualizationViewer<Checkpoint, Route>(graphLayout, new Dimension(
            PropertiesHelper.getWindowWidth(), PropertiesHelper.getWindowHeight()));

    visualizationViewer.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new CheckpointLabelTransformer());
    visualizationViewer.getRenderer().getVertexLabelRenderer().setPosition(Renderer.VertexLabel.Position.CNTR);
    visualizationViewer.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer(new CheckpointColorTransformer());
    visualizationViewer.getRenderContext().setEdgeDrawPaintTransformer(new RouteColorTransformer());
    visualizationViewer.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(new RouteLabelTransformer());

    final ImageIcon mapBackground = createMapBackground();

    if (mapBackground != null) {
        mapBackgroundImagePaintable = new BackgroundImagePaintable(visualizationViewer, mapBackground);
        visualizationViewer.addPreRenderPaintable(mapBackgroundImagePaintable);
    }
    add(visualizationViewer);
    scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(1000,100));

}
```

VisualizationViewer is a class that extends JPanel. Placing scrollRectToVisible in this constructor didn't works.

Any tips? Perhaps this implementation is wrong, where Jcomponent contains Jpanel itself?

Comment: there are two/three ways, but nobody knows what did you tried, for better help sooner edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Do you control the code for the `JApplet`?  While it is possible to put an applet in a frame, it is not a good idea.

Comment: I change the implementation a bit. Instead Japplet my class, which is added to Jframe, extends Jcomponent. In this class I add the Jpanel element (this is required by Jung library, which I use to visualize the graph). But I still can't find a way to scroll the view.

Answer (score 3):

Use method

```
public void scrollRectToVisible(Rectangle aRect)
```

of the JComponent added in JScrollPane

Comment: I don't understand. Now I've got Japplet in Jframe. I should add JScrollPane and add Japplet to it?